# Issue using SQLLDR unable to pass in date 'YYYYMMDD' from CVS to oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, sql-loader

Hi I am new to using sqlldr. I am trying to send the data from a csv file into DB.

csv file looks like this employee.dat:

```
id,code,dNum,name,last,StartDate,EndDate
MA2001,gg,0011,John,Smith,20020127,20020127
```

I have a control file that I am passing to sqlldr that looks like this:

```
OPTIONS(skip=1,bindsize=20000000,readsize=20000000,rows=1024)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE SOMETHING_ADMIN.EMPLOYEE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  "id"
  ,"code"
  ,"dNum"    FLOAT            
  ,"name"
  ,"last"
  ,"StartDate"   DATE "YYYYMMDD"
  ,"EndDate"  DATE "YYYYMMDD"
)
```

When I execute to load I get the following error:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table Record 1: Rejected - Error on table SOMETHING_ADMIN.EMPLOYEE, column "StartDate".
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE" (
  "id" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  "code" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  "dNum" NUMBER(8,0),
  "name" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  "last" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  "StartDate" DATE,
  "EndDate" DATE,
);
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it seems like a simple question but I just cant figure out.

thank you

Comment: HI can you please edit the question and show toe EMPLOYEE table definition?

Comment: Sorry about that yes Ill add that right now

Comment: Did you try something like `"StartDate" "to_date(:StartDate, 'YYYYMMDD')"`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic thank you! I had not tried something like that but now I got this error: SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable :StartDate in SQL string for column "StartDate".

Comment: What about passing the date format in single quotes: `"StartDate"   DATE 'YYYYMMDD'`?

Comment: yes I tried that one but just got the original error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recreate the table (oh, yes - please, avoid enclosing *anything* into double quotes in Oracle; no luck with that, ever) so that "date" columns are `VARCHAR2` (why? So that we'd make sure that they *will* be loaded, for debugging purposes) and load data, this is what you get:

```
ID     CODE             DNUM NAME    LAST    STARTDATE  ENDDATE
------ ---------- ---------- ------- ------- ---------- ----------
ma2001 gg                  0         john    smith      20020127
```

See the `DNUM` and `NAME` columns? Everything is shifted right, so date value - which was supposed to be stored into the `STARTDATE` column - now is in `ENDDATE`, while `enddate`'s value is *lost*.

---

Back to the original table:

```
SQL> desc employee
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(30)
 CODE                                               VARCHAR2(10)
 DNUM                                               NUMBER(8)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 LAST                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 STARTDATE                                          DATE
 ENDDATE                                            DATE

SQL>
```

Control file; the only "specification" is left to date format, i.e. remove `FLOAT` (why did you use it at all?):

```
OPTIONS(skip=1)
LOAD DATA
infile *
truncate
INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  id
  ,code
  ,dNum     
  ,name
  ,last
  ,StartDate date 'yyyymmdd'
  ,EndDate   date 'yyyymmdd'
)

begindata
id,code,dnum,name,last,startdate,enddate
ma2001,gg,0011,john,smith,20020127,20020127
```

Loading session & result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test11.ctl log=test11.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ╚et Lis 24 22:07:47 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1

SQL> select * From employee;

ID     CODE             DNUM NAME    LAST    STARTDATE  ENDDATE
------ ---------- ---------- ------- ------- ---------- ----------
ma2001 gg                 11 john    smith   27.01.02   27.01.02
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! I have to give a presentation on this soon! you were right it was because of the stupid FLOAT and I changed   
"dNum" NUMBER(8,0) to the way you had it:
  "dNum" NUMBER(8),
. It worked thank you! Also thank you as well to OldProgrammer you were right as well.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle parser is sometimes quite stupid with the errors it returns. I don't think it liked the FLOAT keyword.  Removed that and unneeded quotes, and seems to work for me.

```
OPTIONS(skip=1,bindsize=20000000,readsize=20000000,rows=1024)
LOAD DATA
infile 'test.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  id 
  ,code 
  ,dNum       
  ,name    
  ,last    
  ,StartDate   DATE 'YYYYMMDD'
  ,EndDate   DATE 'YYYYMMDD'  
  )
```